# i would like to change the method name main() to mymain()

Tags: java

i would like to change the method name main to mymain

,it is possiable , (Source change)we have modify the code jre ,
i don't how please tell me if you know

thank you

Comment: If it is the entry point to your program, then the answer is `no`

Comment: As @ScaryWombat stated, the entry point to the program must be `main`. The best you could do would be to create a `mymain` method with your code and call it in `main`. However, this is utterly pointless in most cases.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain *why* you want to do this? Most likely there is a better solution for your actual problem.

Comment: java is open source any one can modify their own if they i am just want to change name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch your program by the default `java` (or `javaw`) utility bundled with JRE, then **no, you can't**.

**BUT...**

You can mimic what the `java` utility does. Roughly speaking:

1. Parse command line;
2. Create a JVM (the hardest part, I think);
3. Instantiate and initialize the classloader(s);
4. Load the "main" class;
5. Instantiate and initialize the `args` array of arguments;
6. Invoke the `main()` method, passing the array;
7. Take care of any exception thrown, printing it to stderr.

Some of these (like parsing the command line) is pure C (or whatever you code in).

Most of it is dealing with the libjvm library (where the JVM actually resides). A though API, I think.

Of course, along the way **you can do whatever you want**, like creating OS threads and running many JVM instances, each one calling a different java method. **Or calling another method, not necessarily `main`** (even passing other arguments, not just `String[]`). Or you can have most of your program coded in C (or whatever) and call specific java methods in specific points and so on.

Take a look at: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/raw-file/jdk7-b24/src/os/linux/launcher/java.c

**Note:** I've never did this.

Comment: thank you for your answers. i am looking for how to change code in jre and accept the main as mymain . edit source code change the behaviour of jvm